Recreating headlight on FBX car model
I have been learning more about Blender rendering and in the process, trying to recreate scenes from pro modelers. My current attempt is the very nice Audi R8 model from Federico-Cuomo.
The part of the model that has me stuck are the headlights as shown below:

The mesh itself does not represent the individual lights:

The model does not have an included texture from what I can tell. I have two possibilities in mind:

Would there be something in the FBX format that Blender is not importing?
Is this an emission texture or shader that is draped on the headlight mesh, which the artist simply didn't include as a downloadable asset?

I want to verify I'm not missing something important before going any further, thank you!

the only mesh we see from your screenshot is the external "glass" of the headlights. If the inside is modeled, gotta look in xray or wireframe to see them through. If it's all done in shaders, then you should have the textures somewhere. Though the materials might not be imported correctly, depending on whether they were made in a standard way understandable by both the FBX  format and Blender.

Wow you're right, I had previously shifted the headlight objects out to see if there was anything special, but it does appear to be fully modeled on the interior. I may just need to play around with the glass material then. I'll post back here if I figure it out!
